# How to delete files using Gutmann method in Linux?

Tags: linux, security, secure-erase

How to delete files using Gutmann method in Linux ? In Windows there are software like Eraser and Gutmann Algorithm Secure File Deletion. How to delete files as like that in Linux systems ?

Answer (score 1):

With `wipe`.

> In normal mode, 34 patterns are used (of which 8 are random). These patterns were recommended in an article from Peter Gutmann (...)

(from `man` page).

Comment: Note that a later edition of that article un-recommends it.